# Can you say "predict" in regression write-up if data is cross-sectional?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Can you say "predict" in a regression write-up if your data is cross-sectional? Or should you stick to language such as X is "associated" or "related to" with Y.

Does *predict* always imply change over time?

Comment: There are few rules in predictive modeling and regression. So, no, prediction is not time dependent and, yes, you can use it to describe cross-sectional data.

Comment: You can always predict what potentially could have been observed. After all, the whole point of a probability model is to describe such potentially observable data. Sure, once it has been observed that's all there is, but other data could have occurred. If not, don't use a probability model.